# Passing a powershell variable as output directory in 7zip

Tags: powershell, 7-zip

I need to execute something like

`7za e $file_path -oC:\Destination`

inside a powershell script, but substitute destination folder (C:\Destination) with a variable. Some like:

`7za e $file_path -o$output_path`

which obviously does not work. The previous statement in fact creates a folder with actual name `$output_path`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this should work, but it doesn't for me for some reason:

```
7za e $file_path -o$($output_path)
```

This will work:

```
$outparam = "-o" + $output_path
7za e $file_path $outparam
```

This will also work (it's just condensing the previous one into one line):

```
7za e $file_path $("-o" + $output_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! That also works -> `& 7za e $file_path "-o${output_path}"`. I just needed those quotes.

Comment: Third option works great.  You rock!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to overcome this but I would still like to now if there any other way to do it.

```
Push-Location ($output_path)
& 7za e $file_path
Pop-Location
```